# FFMpeg - increase processing speed for filter_complex with enable='0'?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am running a FFmpeg command with 'filter_complex', applying a set of consecutive filters, that ultimately will only be applied to some specific frames.

The challenge I'm having is the command performance - regardless of applying the filter to all frames or not, the performance is very similar.

Here are some examples:

1. Apply a filter to every frame (alternate between 2 different filters, every 15 frames):

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -i "image1.png" -i "image2.png" -filter_complex "[0:v]format=gbrp[f],[0:v]format=gbrp[f1],[0:v]format=gbrp[f2],[1:v]format=gbrp[w1],[2:v]format=gbrp[w2],[f1][w1]blend=all_mode='darken':enable='lt(mod(n\,30)\,15)'[fw1];[f2][w2]blend=all_mode='lighten':enable='gte(mod(n\,30)\,15)'[fw2];[f][fw1]blend=all_mode='lighten':enable='lt(mod(n\,30)\,15)'[ftmp];[ftmp][fw2]blend=all_mode='darken':enable='gte(mod(n\,30)\,15)'" output.mp4
```

Processing speed=0.625x

2. Apply the filter every 15 frames (2 filters alternating every 30 frames):

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -i "image1.png" -i "image2.png" -filter_complex "[0:v]format=gbrp[f],[0:v]format=gbrp[f1],[0:v]format=gbrp[f2],[1:v]format=gbrp[w1],[2:v]format=gbrp[w2],[f1][w1]blend=all_mode='darken':enable='eq(mod(n\,30)\,15)'[fw1];[f2][w2]blend=all_mode='lighten':enable='eq(mod(n\,30)\,15)'[fw2];[f][fw1]blend=all_mode='lighten':enable='eq(mod(n\,30)\,15)'[ftmp];[ftmp][fw2]blend=all_mode='darken':enable='eq(mod(n\,30)\,15)'" output.mp4
```

Processing speed=0.661x

3. Set all "enabled" properties to 0 (therefore not applying any filter at all):

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -i "image1.png" -i "image2.png" -filter_complex "[0:v]format=gbrp[f],[0:v]format=gbrp[f1],[0:v]format=gbrp[f2],[1:v]format=gbrp[w1],[2:v]format=gbrp[w2],[f1][w1]blend=all_mode='darken':enable='0'[fw1];[f2][w2]blend=all_mode='lighten':enable='0'[fw2];[f][fw1]blend=all_mode='lighten':enable='0'[ftmp];[ftmp][fw2]blend=all_mode='darken':enable='0'" output.mp4
```

Processing speed=0.663x

4. Apply a basic "Negate" filter to the video:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -i "image1.png" -i "image2.png" -filter_complex "[0:v]format=gbrp[f],[f]negate" output.mp4
```

Processing speed=1.23x

The performance is very similar for the cases 1. to 3., however I was expecting a similar performance between the two last ones since, in theory, nothing is processed on the 3. - however, with every filter turned off, the performance is very similar to having all filters enabled.

Is there any way I am able to rewrite this command in order to increase the performance?
The final goal will is to increase the performance for the case 2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are applying the format filter (thrice, for some reason) to the video and that's enabled for all frames.

Comment: @gyan yes, the goal is to apply all these filters, but for some specific frames only. My question is if there's any way to rewrite the command to increase its performance. Thanks